# Old PC, extremely slow hdd speed

Tags: hard-drive, performance, intel-celeron

I've just got an old pc that I was hoping that my young lad could use for educational websites and the odd old game. It's a celeron based pc but seems ok apart from the ridiculous disk (possibly bus) speeds I'm seeing. The HDD is fairly new SATA II with no SMART issues, I have changed the thermal paste on the processor to ensure the slow down wasn't caused by this.

I haven't managed to test the actual read/write speeds yet but for instance I'm installing a game, Need for speed: hot pursuit, an old game that has so far taken around 3 hours with the time remaining 3 hours, this is ridiculous for any system.

Any ideas what could be wrong please?

Foxconn G35
Intel Celeron 440
2GB SD RAM
Windows 7
Seagate 2TB

Comment: Looking at the specs I think that it is a reasonable speed. The system is not meant for windows 7 it has 1 core which is probably all used up by the system itself. Windows itself already uses 1,5gb to 2gb ram. I kinda think your CPU is bottlenecking. Yet again I am not sure. I am not sure if the board can even handle sata II looking at its end of life date from the processor.

Comment: When bought the system was installed with Vista which is heavier than Windows 7 isn't it? It's quite possible the CPU is bottlenecking. I'm sure I've seen reasonable performance from this system running Windows 7 in the past and wouldn't expect this behaviour, although I could be wrong.

Comment: That is quite interesting to be honest. But I think you should check the read/write speed of the disk first. you should also check the task manager to see what is bottlenecking while installing.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I'm seeing 100% CPU usage but processes are only showing setup.tmp using ~15% and very little activity from other processes. It's an odd one. I've literally just been given another old system to see if I can use any parts of it. This has a P4 which should be better than the celeron, so with any joy I might see an improvement. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: P4 chip in, massive improvement, guess that answers our question.

Answer (score 0):

Celeron Processor bottlenecking, replaced processor with P4, problem fixed.